# Quick Volume of Revolution with Lines Question

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

So I was given the following prompt:

"What is the volume of the solid generated when the region in the first quadrant bounded by the graph of $y=x^3$, the $y$-axis, and the horizontal line $y=1$ is revolved about the $y$-axis?"

I guess I'm just a bit confused about what the integral set up might look like here. I understand the basics of the Disc and Washer methods, but I'm a bit confused about how that would apply here. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You can find intersection of $y=1, y = x^3$ which is $(1,1)$. So the integral to find volume can be set up using washer method as

$0 \leq x \leq y^{1/3} \ $ where $x$ is the radius around $y-$axis
$0 \leq y \leq 1$

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \int_0^{y^{1/3}} 2 \pi x \ dx \ dy$

Or it can be set up using shell method as

$x^3 \leq y \leq 1$
$0 \leq x \leq 1$

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \int_{x^3}^1 2\pi x \ dy \ dx$

Comment: So what were you coming up with for an answer? I'm a bit confused about integrating when it involves a shell integral like you laid out. I do appreciate how thorough your answer is I'm understanding it much better.

Comment: The answer is $\frac{3\pi}{5}$.